# Purch Agreement Header and Line view ax 2012

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I am having this issue on PurchAgreement form, I create a new purchase agreement in the header view and when I go to line view (without saving this purch agreement ) it shows me all agreement Lines avalaible

Then when I save it they are empty as they should be, but I think it is wrong to show all the agreement lines while I still have not created the purchase agreement.

Is there any property or  method that solves this?

Comment: You could try to save the agreement header record when switching to line view.

Answer (score 1):

This should only happen if you succeded to create agreement lines `AgreementLine` with zero value in the `Agreement` field. The zero agreement lines are auto dynalinked with the still zero RecId of the agreement header.

You should not be able to create such lines via the user interface as the field is mandatory.

Comment: Actually ,added a query in init method of the form which does not allow to take any value when creating the purch agreement.Thank you for your help